# xe:viewJsonService only returns 10 rows

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm using the viewJsonService to retrieve rows from a Notes view, but only ever get the first 10 rows returned. I haven't specified a value for "searchMaxDocs", but even if I put in a value greater than 10, I still only get the first 10 rows of the view returned.

```
    <xe:restService id="restServiceEvents" pathInfo="getEvents">
        <xe:this.service>
            <xe:viewJsonService defaultColumns="true"
                viewName="vwEvents" var="eventRow">
            </xe:viewJsonService>
        </xe:this.service>
    </xe:restService>
```

Is this limit defined somewhere else? How can I retrieve all rows from the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set property `count` to `"100000"`. It will deliver all documents, at least first 100000.

```xml
        <xe:viewJsonService defaultColumns="true"
            viewName="vwEvents" var="eventRow" count="100000">
        </xe:viewJsonService>
```

Comment: I'm getting 10 documents returned regardless of the value of searchMaxDocs. I've tried "0", "1", "5", "100", "100000" - and get 10 returned every time! Could something else be overriding this?

Comment: Thank you - I only saw your edit after I had posted my previous comment :)